# Global variable becomes null sometimes

Tags: android

I have a variable declared in my base base that extends Application.

The variable is static  and i am able to set it and access it just fine. However on some devices it is null sometimes.

```
public class Application extends android.app.Application {

public static ArrayList<String> nextPage;


@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
      ...
    }
}
```

```
<application
            android:name="Application"
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.MyTheme" >
      ...
```

I am referencing it like this: `Application.nextPage`

I am using bug sense and I see there have been 30 errors where this variable is null. It only happens rarely, because the app gets thousands of users per day and this error has only occured 30 times this week.

Is anyone aware of such an issue or what might be causing it?

Problem devices:

```
SCH-I605 19%     3
SM-N900P 13%     2
ST26i 13%        2
SAMSUNG-SGH-I337 13% 2
SHV-E210S 13%    2
DROID RAZR HD 13%    2
SCH-I200 13%     2
DROID RAZR 7%    1
```

Problem occurred on the following SDK:

```
4.1.2 40%    12
4.3 30%      9
4.4.2 10%    3
4.1.1 7%     2
4.2.2 7%     2
4.0.3 4%     1
2.3.6 4%     1
```

Comment: sometimes when could you be more specific? Is this happen when your application is running at front or when it's in background ?

Comment: @VaibhavAjayGupta My application only runs in the foreground.By "sometimes" i mean my application had 20k sessions this week and 30 of these error. so its only rarely does this happen

Comment: Did you try killing your app and checking that value? I guess that becomes null when user kills the app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where in your app do you initialize nextPage?

I would recommend adding `nextPage = new ArrayList<String>();` in onCreate of Application, or simply directly in the field variable.

If you initialize nextPage in an activity, then a possible scenario of null could be:

- App starts
- Activity starts - nextPage is set and valid
- User leaves the App
- Android destroys App (possibly after some time)
- A broadcast is sent (if you have defined broadcast listening in manifest)
- App is started (but not Activity)
- The nextPage list is null

Not knowing how your app is working, this is a thought example but could be an indication of your problem.

Comment: You are right. It's not exctly what happens in my app but it solved the problem. I tested it by leaving the app in the background for a few minutes while I opened many other apps. when I went back to my app it crashed because as you said the OS claimed the memory for nextPage. Thanks!